# Write in registry in order to add application in start menu

Tags: vb.net, registry, startmenu

I have made a program in Visual Basic and I want to add this program in user's start menu by code. How can I do that?

I know that there is a folder in

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
```

where I can add my application's shortcut, but I think I have, also, to write in user's registry.

And that's my problem: I don't know what to write in registry in order to add app in start menu. A simple location in registry will help me if you don't know vb code.

Comment: Are you installing this through an installer or just running it? It will require it to be installed and a new registry entry. This can be handled through the installer if you are using one. If not it would be a different route of course.

Comment: Thank's for your answer! I am just running it..I am not using an installer..Basicly,I am making my own installer and that's why I need it..I know that it sounds waste of time,but I prefer my own-designed installer.

Comment: Its usually services, BG apps like updaters which are posted to the Registry, a folder shortcut is all you need for a basic app.  However the folder path you show adds it for All Users, `C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` adds for the current user only

Comment: So, I don't  have to write in the Registry.Thank's @Plutonix !